# Blender lags with 40,00,000 faces

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, system, polycount

Blender lags with 40,00,000 faces in my Laptop with 8 gb ram ryzen 5 4600h cpu , gtx 1650. What must be the reason ? Is it my Ram?

Comment: Hello :). 4 million faces by themselves won't fill 8GB RAM. Check your system resources manager, and you'll see what's the bottleneck. Related: [Would 1 million faces/vertices be too much for Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221339/78972)

Answer (score 1):

400 000 faces is a big number of faces and yes, the RAM may be a problem. But it also depends on the speed of your RAM, so what's your RAM speed and is your notebook humming when you try to move around, or move some vertices in Blender?

Comment: if you count the zeros...he wrote 4.000.000 ....but i don't know whether this was a mistake... ;)

Comment: Yeah, yeah I thought about it aswell, but 400k is a big number too and 4 000 000 is a even bigger number. I suppose it's going to lag with both numbers of faces I would say.

Comment: thanks for the responses guys, I actually meant 4 million and not 400k. In my case blender runs really smooth until the 4 million mark, Then things started to react really slower. By the way I have seen people sculpt in a really high poly count doing much more complex projects

Comment: My RAM speed is 3200 MHz and no, there is no humming of sorts in my case but there is a delayed reaction when i sculpt as well as move the vertices in edit mode

Comment: Your whole Blender starts lagging or for example you have subdivided object and you start moving some vertices?

Comment: yes everything i do gets lagged after i reach that amount of faces

Comment: That's really weird that it is starting to lag at 4 mil. vertices.  Probably the last thing I can say is that you can try to reinstall Blender or install a newer version.